# ¿Como agregar una pestaña al archivo CSV creado en Python?

Tags: python, csv

Hola Buenas tardes ¿Cómo están?,

Les comento, quiero generar un archivo CSV que contenga 2 pestañas "A" y "B" de las cuales voy a asignarles columnas vacías (estas columnas luego serán rellenadas importando otros archivos csv).

¿Se puede generar 2 pestañas en un archivo CSV o no tengo forma?, estoy buscando pero no encuentro como hacerlo, sino una alternativa sería cambiar el formato de CSV a xls.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo entendido que los archivos CSV no aceptan pestañas al ser texto con valores planos

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "2 pestañas"? Porque un archivo CSV es texto plano con formato (CSV), y el concepto de "pestañas" es algo de una interfaz de usuario, que no se puede replicar en un fichero de texto plano

Comment: Gracias, si entonces voy a averiguar cómo generar un excel con pestañas con python porque la idea es que genere un archivo xls o cvs con dos pestañas para importarle datos

Comment: Si quieres tener libertad de trabajar con excel en Python, te recomiendo el framework [OpenPyxl](https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/).